# Hund's rule for comparing term symbol energies in excited state

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

This question was asked in an exam:

> The lowest energy electronic state for excited state carbon atom is,
> a. $^1D_2$
> b. $^3D_1$
> c. $^3D_3$
> d. $^3D_2$

Although we have been taught Hund's rule for determining the relative energies for various term symbols in the ground state, I haven't read anything about the rules for excited state anywhere. I couldn't not find it in the book I use i.e. Atkins, Physical Chemistry.

I am really confused about how to solve this.

Comment: summarising (a) lowest multiplicity lowest energy (b) with a given multiplicity largest L lowest energy (c) Atoms with less than 1/2 filled shell lowest J lowest energy.  Does not the excited state just means an extra electron 'upstairs' such as $s^2p^2\to s^1p^3$

Comment: But on subwhat shell are we going to apply the less than half or more than half filled subshell rule?

Comment: Hund's rules strictly assume LS coupling and application to excited states is not reliable. Of course you can try to apply them in a similar manner as for the ground state, but treat the outcome with caution